# Looping inside block return

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, block-editor, color-picker

I have a custom block that allows me to choose a color. This is how the block's return function looks:

```
                return (
                        el( 'div', { },
                                el( 'div',
                                        { },
                                        el( ColorPalette, { 
                                                value: props.attributes.paletteData[0],
                                                onChange: updatePalette,
                                        } )
                                )

                        ) 
                );
```

At the moment it shows a single color picker.

However I would like my block to show as many color pickers as there are values inside `props.attributes.paletteData`.

How can I achieve that? I was hoping I'd be able to loop as you do in React like so:

```
return (
   {
      props.attributes.paletteData.map(value => {
         return (
            el( ColorPalette, {
               value: etc,
               onChange: etc,
            }
         )
      }
   }
```

But I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just change this:

```js
el( ColorPalette, {
    value: props.attributes.paletteData[0],
    onChange: updatePalette,
} )
```

to this:

```js
el( 'div', {}, props.attributes.paletteData.map(
    function ( value, i ) {
        return el( ColorPalette, {
            'value': value,
            onChange: updatePalette,
            key: 'color-' + i, // required
            //...
        } );
    }
) )
```

I.e. Pass an array of elements as the third parameter:

```js
el( 'div', {}, <array of elements here> )
```

Or am I not understanding you?

Comment: Yeah sorry that's on me. Been using ES6 too much and can't remember how to do basic JS.